# How to plot several signals with different filled shades to show statistical behaviour of the data?

Tags: matlab, plot, statistics, matlab-figure

I have several measurements for a signal over `T` seconds. All data is stored in a `T  by M` matrix. Where `M` is `4000` and `T` is `40` seconds (First Fig). Most observations are within an interval. Therefore, I would like to generate a plot that uses shades with different intensities to show concentration of data (Similar to the right side of the second Fig).

[image]

[image]

Comment: One way could be to assume your 2D graph is an image. Translate each data point `Matrix(t,m)` to image coordinates and increment pixel values. You will end up with an image where the intensity of each pixel shows how many lines have intersected with that pixel. The higher the intensity, the "brighter" the pixel.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the `patch` command, but you will need to compute the polygon that encloses the upper and lower bounds of each region (determined by your std values at each time point).

for example, you can do something like this, use a linearly varying random numbers for a test

```
data=rand(40,4000).*repmat((1:40)',1,4000);
t=1:size(data,1);
hold on;
for i=3:-1:1
   y1=mean(data')+i*std(data');
   y2=mean(data')-i*std(data');
   area=[t fliplr(t); y1 fliplr(y2)]';
   patch(area(:,1),area(:,2),1/i*[t fliplr(t)]);
end
colormap(hot)
```

you can change the color 'C' input to patch to adjust its color distribution and transparency. patch objects also have many properties that you can set to adjust its visual appearance.

Comment: Thank you. But still there is an issue. The proposed code generates a symmetrical shape over x axis and doesn't encompass the real shape of the data. I guess it's due to what you mentioned:  "upper and lower bounds of each region". Would you clarify more and show how can I define the boundaries. @fangq